# What is the best way to toggle user defined column name or default column name in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

What is the best approach for stored procedure to toggle between user defined column names or default column name

Here is what I have done so far. This is fine for small query, is there a better way of doing this for larger query.

```
-- Drop stored procedure if it already exists
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.procedures 
        WHERE schema_id = schema_id('dbo')
        AND name = N'sp_test')
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_test
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
    -- /* Declare parameters */
    @columnName BIT =0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SELECT statement to fetch record
    IF(@columnName =1)
        (
            SELECT
                TOP 100
                IM.INC_REF,
                IM.ID
            FROM
                dbo.TEST AS IM
        )
    ELSE
        (
            SELECT
                TOP 100
                IM.INC_REF AS REF,
                IM.ID AS ID
            FROM
                dbo.TEST AS IM
        )
END
GO

-- ============================================
-- Execute stored procedure
-- ============================================

DECLARE @columnName AS BIT

SET @columnName =0


EXEC [dbo].[sp_test] @columnName
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will you have a specific patter when using alies?

Comment: Let say I have a specific pattern for now, how could this be done?

Comment: Don't have answer for you question right now. just asked query.

Comment: Best way - don't do it. SQL Server caches the execution plan of a stored procedure the first time it's executed - that's one of the advantages of using stored procedures. This means it will cache the execution plan corresponding to the first parameter. This is guaranteed to cause problems as SQL Server finds it has the wrong plan and recompile the procedure every time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is mostly correct. However, it will not recompile every time. It is much worse than that. It will use the cached execution plan even though it is less efficient. Also, any query will generate an execution plan which is then cached. This caching is not a benefit from stored procedures that other queries don't have.

Comment: I agree with Panagiotis, don't do this to yourself. Also, you have top 100 in your queries but no order by. This means you don't which 100 rows you will get. This whole notion of conditional aliasing of columns is a bit strange. What are you really trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @SeanLange: Assuming the SP is returning the same results each time, and just the column names of the results are different, I don't understand why this would cause a problem.  Wouldn't the execution plan be the same either way?

Comment: You are probably right @Dave.Gugg. It still seems very odd to have this type of conditional aliasing. This sort of indicates it is being used by multiple applications and the columns names need to change between them. In my experience that is also a good indicator that these queries are going to migrate apart from each and they will end up being very different queries.

Answer (score 0):

When we need different results from a stored procedure based on a parameter, we'll call one of two "sub" stored procedures.  In your case, that would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
    -- /* Declare parameters */
    @columnName BIT = 0
AS
    BEGIN
        IF ( @columnName = 1 )
            EXEC dbo.[sp_test1]
        ELSE
            EXEC dbo.[sp_test2]
    END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[sp_test1]
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 100
                IM.INC_REF ,
                IM.ID
        FROM    dbo.TEST AS IM
    END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[sp_test2]
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 100
                IM.INC_REF AS REF ,
                IM.ID AS ID
        FROM    dbo.TEST AS IM
    END

GO
```

I've found this gets around the issue of badly cached plans.